# What are the plugins installed with QGIS 2.18.14, at the beginning?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

I want to organize the plugins to make QGIS open faster and get more memory from PC, but I don´t know what plugins are crucial for QGIS.

[The Core plugins seems to be different](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html)...

Is there a place to see what are the plugins installed with QGIS at the very beginning?

Comment: If you go into your QGIS directory (e.g. `/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis/plugins/`), you can see the core providers and plugins which come with the installation. As @AndreJ mentioned, you cannot uninstall these from the manager so if you find one which you can uninstall, it would be an external plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No plugins are really crucial to run QGIS. It just depends what you need.

You can uncheck all plugins, and uninstall all non-core plugins from the plugin manager. Core plugins can't be uninstalled with the manager.